# media query no funciona

Tags: html, css

Estoy intentando cambiar la opacidad de una foto al achicar la ventana y no logro hacerlo. Lo curioso es que si en vez de cambiar la opacidad coloco un display: none esto si funciona pero no lo primero. Intenté cambiar de tipo de selector CSS y el error sigue ocurriendo. ¿A qué se debe?

html

`<div > <img src="gubernamental.jpg" alt="imagen edificio" id="primera-foto"> </div>`

css:

```
#primera-foto {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 80px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  
  #primera-foto {
    width: 50%; 
    opacity: 1;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Comprueba que no estes pisando la regla más abajo en tu css

Comment: Prueba con `@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asegúrate de que el media query está bien, y prueba a ponerle un ***!important*** en la opacidad del *media-query*:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 
  #primera-foto {
    width: 50%; 
    opacity: 1 !important;   
    }
}
```

Si con el **!important** te funciona, eso quiere decir que el problema está en que otro CSS te está pisando esa propiedad *opacity*.

Espero haberte ayudado! :)

Comment: gracias era eso. lo curioso es que no tengo otros elementos CSS que lo pisen. quizá bootstrap de alguna manera rara